# Git no me permite hacer pull

Tags: git

tengo un problema y es que en ubuntu tengo un proyecto clonado por medio de git, ahora mi problema es que me sale esto, cuando tiro el comando git pull, ahora la idea es que me tome los ultimos cambios que hice.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes que hacer un rebase a esa rama para que vayas resolviendo los conflictos commit por commit

Comment: y eso como se hace?, o sea ya lo solucione, me toco manualmente arreglar los conflictos literal copiando codigo por codigo, pero por medio de git me gustaria hacerlo.

Comment: Si simplemente quieres bajarte lo que hay en el repo y no te importa lo que tienes en local, `git pull -f`. Si quieres mantener tus cambios en local porque luego quieres pushearlos al repo, te tocará arreglar los conflictos uno por uno (o usar alguna herramienta gráfica que te permita seleccionar qué juego de cambios prefieres, el Visual Studio Code se integra muy bien con git para estos temas por ejemplo). Si quieres mantener tus cambios locales y no te importa lo que hay en el repo, `git push -f`. Ten en cuenta que usar el flag `-f` es *destructivo* y machaca el historial de git.